# Neither pandas.read_html nor BeautifulSoup can find all tables on webpage

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the 3rd and 6th tables from a webpage (https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/) but pandas.read_html and BeautifulSoup are both only finding the first two tables on the page. Here is what I've tried.

```
url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/'

data_pd = pd.read_html(url)
print(len(data_pd))
```

Output:

```
2
```

and also

```
url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    print(table.get('class'))
```

Output:

```
['sortable', 'stats_table']
['sortable', 'stats_table']
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the way the webpage is formatted, but is there anything I can do to grab the tables that I need?

Comment: The tables after the first two are loaded via JavaScript, which cannot be accessed with the `requests` library alone. This can be verified be viewing the contents from `curl`, or looking at the page with JavaScript turned off. You'll need something like Selenium or PyQt (QtWebkit / QtWebEngine) which will load the page, and then you can pass the content off to BeautifulSoup

Comment: Thank you, jrd1, this worked. I used Selenium to load the page then passed to BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use Selenium to let the page render then pull in the html. However I try to avoid Selenium if I could as to avoid the overhead.

The better option though is through the simple request, the static html does have the other tables in there, but within the comments. You could do a) BeautifulSoup does have the ability to pull out the Comments to then parse those tables. Or simply remove the comment tags and then parse.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/'
response = requests.get(url).text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")

data_pd = pd.read_html(response)
print(len(data_pd))
```

**Output:**

```
print(len(data_pd))
13
```

OR Using BEautifulSoup to co through the comments:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/'
result = requests.get(url).text
data = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

comments = data.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

data_pd = pd.read_html(url)
for each in comments:
    if '<table' in str(each):
        data_pd.append(pd.read_html(str(each))[0])
        
print(len(data_pd))
```